LSTM Variational auto encoder not learning with Pytorch
I'm trying to train an LSTM Variational Autoencoder, but I cannot figure out why the model is not making any progress, the loss gets stuck immediately.
Here is my code and training loop. The sequences consist of 10 numbers normalized between 0 and 1, compressed into a bottleneck of 5 and then decoded. The numbers are not random - they are reaction times of players. I have tried training it on 500, 10k, 100k, and 500k examples with no success.
I am trying to encode with an LSTM and decode with a normal dense layer. Please let me know if you need any additional information or find anything else. Thank you!
VAE: https://hastebin.skyra.pw/yayecitowa.py
Train: https://hastebin.skyra.pw/oyucawefuf.py
Output example at epoch 1 and 100: https://hastebin.skyra.pw/ucodelibut
Loss on epoch 1: 21.7765
Loss on epoch 100: 21.7266
